# Jquery Validation

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I want to validate a form in such a way that when the page loads focus should be on first element and if I try to click on any other textbox it should throw an error message and focus should be back on the first one.Same way it is repeated for all other boxes.I have achieved this using Jquery But havenot used Validate.js or bValidate.js.So the code has become very lengthy.Can anyone suggest how to use this plugins effectively to achieve this sort of things.As by seeing codes inside those plugins I am getting confused.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advence.....:-)

Comment: Sounds very annoying...

Comment: Please do NOT do that. `alert()` windows (at least the pre-firefox4 ones) are extremely annoying since you have to press a key/click to get rid of them and they block the **whole browser** in most browsers instead of just the current page. Simply mark the fields as erroneous and prevent the user from submitting the form until all fields validate.

Comment: I wont -1 because I dont want you to get -3, delete, and badge from it...

Answer (score 0):

Seriously... Just dont submit until you have the correct data... DONT ALERT!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that with validation, as it's not clear to the user that the fields have to be typed in a specific order.

If you need the users to fill in the fields one after the other, you should disable all fields except the first one. Once you have typed something in it, you can enable the next field. It's still a big annoying, but at least it's clear to the user what's happening. You shouldn't have to use trial and error to figure out how to use the form.